# How can you use vim suffixes for NERDTreeIgnore?

Tags: vim, gvim

Since I already define my "intermediary" files with `set suffixes=.o,~,...`, how can I reuse that to make NERDTree not show those files?

It seems anti-DRY to put them all again in a different variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy your `suffixes` to the `NERDTreeIgnore` variable.

As `suffixes` holds plain strings that `Vim` matches at the end of file names and `NERDTreeIgnore` holds regular expressions matched against complete names, to match similar files you'd have to

- anchor the `suffixes` strings to the end of names by appending `$`, and
- escape all regex-specific characters.

For example:

```
let NERDTreeIgnore = []
for suffix in split(&suffixes, ',')
    let NERDTreeIgnore += [ escape(suffix, '.~') . '$' ]
endfor
```

**Note**: This only escapes `.` (dot) and `~` (tilde) as they seem to be the only relevant characters appearing in the default `suffixes`. Add more characters to `escape()`'s second argument if you use different `suffixes` or need a more general solution.